# Hover image - display div over it

Tags: jquery, css, image, facebook, hover

On hover I want a link apear at the top-right of the image. Just like on your profile picture on Facebook, where it says "Change Picture".

I have tried to to get it working with a bit of jquery but had no luck, as it doesn't go t the right of the image. The images are going to be different sizes as they are profile pictures. So whatever the size, it needs to stay at the top-right of the image.

JQuery:

```
$(".imgHover").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25)
           .end().children(".hover").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1)
           .end().children(".hover").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imgHover">
    <div class="hover"><a href="htpp://google.com">Edit</a></div>
    <img src="http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgHover .hover { 
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the issue that you want it in the upper right corner, or beside it entirely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the way I done it:
CSS:

```
.imgHover {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.imgHover .hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imgHover">
<div class="hover"><a href="htpp://google.com">Edit</a></div>
<img src="http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgHover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
});
```

Test this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evJRm/).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .imgHover {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }
    .imgHover .hover {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".imgHover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25).end().children(".hover").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
});
</script>

<div class="imgHover"><div class="hover"><a href="htpp://google.com">Edit</a></div><img src="http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg" alt=""></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks, but the link displays at the bottom of the image. :/

Comment: You've changed something or did not provide some code that is changing it.  If you run my example stand-alone, you'll see that it works as intended (edit link in top-right of image).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. I managed to do it in the end

Answer (score 2):

If the imgHover is made to match its contents, then it should just have `position:relative` and the hover class have `position:absolute` and `top:0;right:0`

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: @Bazzz, or is yours the same as mine ? :p we must have posted at around the same time..

Comment: If you click the "oldest" tab you can see that mine is 'just' above yours, so slightly older, but indeed we posted around the same time. Let's say 'great minds think alike' and post at the same time :)

Comment: its a deal @Bazzz :) (*i know you posted first.. was just joking*)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. I managed to do it in the end

Comment: @hart, the solution you posted is exactly what i suggested, so not sure why it did not work .. the only difference is the `display:inline` which i mention as " *If the `imgHover` is made to match its contents* ". Glad you got it sorted though :)

Comment: @Gaby there is a slight difference between them. .hover has right:0
z-index: 2 and display: none. + .imgHover has display: inline. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

make your image a background for div with relative positioning
and add inner div to it with the overlay content
style it with display:none

then 
    imgdiv:hover innerdiv{display:block} 
will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You need to absolute position the link in a container that has position different than the normal flow. In this example I use relative for that on the container. Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="imgHover">
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <a href="http://google.com">Edit</a>
    <img src="http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imgHover { float: left; }
.imgContainer { position: relative; }
.imgContainer a { display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; background: Green;}
```

Comment: Had no luck with this either. :(

Comment: May I ask why? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your requirement but if I look here http://jsfiddle.net/C4LSz/ I clearly see the Edit link with green background at the top right corner of the image.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was my fault, I had no luck with using it with jquery making it show if you hover ver the image. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Ah I see, it's because I found your question by looking for unanswered questions with tag "css", so that's why I thought your problem was css related. :) I do see now that the first tag you used is jquery.