# Div over image Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Snippet based on http://jsfiddle.net/evJRm/ ([Hover image - display div over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306801/hover-image-display-div-over-it))

The problem is, when the window resizes, the text and the image get seperated from each other (the image starts on a new line). How do I fix this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='img-container'>
        <div class='img-text'>text</div>
        <img style='margin-top:10px;' width='150' height='225' src='http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class='img-container'>
        <div class='img-text'>text</div>
        <img style='margin-top:10px;' width='150' height='225' src='http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class='img-container'>
        <div class='img-text'>text</div>
        <img style='margin-top:10px;' width='150' height='225' src='http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg' />
    </div>
</div>

.img-container{
    width:150px;
    height:225px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin:5px;
}
.img-text{
    top:20px;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w23ch/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` for the image container and update the positioning accordingly.

The height and width won't affect inline elements, which makes it difficult to get a correct positioning.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/7ewrM/)

```
.img-container{
    width:150px;
    height:225px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
.img-text{
    top:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: How does this have anything to do with bootstrap? Edit: I see the question is lacking the same thing. Nevermind :)